custom list bullets with tikz
I'm trying to make my own bullets for itemized and enumerated lists. I'm rather surprised that latex has not properly been developed on this point. By default the first level is a round bullet, but if \sfdefault is set it will be a small square. To change it back to the round bullet one has to use $\bullet$. And the second level is --.
Using instead \blacksquare does not fit nicely with the size of the previous level.
Here is my mwe: The goal of this post is to get from users nice rounded bullets without excessive size.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pifont,enumitem,tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=-.75ex]{%
  \node[shape=circle,minimum size=2.6ex,draw,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny] (char) {#1};}}

\renewcommand*\bullet{\tikz{%
  \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle [radius=.43ex];}}
\newcommand*\square{\tikz{%
  \fill[fill=black] (0,0) rectangle (.9ex,.9ex);}}

\setlist[enumerate]{label=\protect\circled{\arabic*}}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\bullet}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\square}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{enumerate}

  \item un
  \item deu

    \begin{itemize}
      \item deuzième niveau
      \item ...
    \end{itemize}

  \item tro
  \item qua
  \item cin
    \begin{itemize}
      \item deuzième niveau
      \item ...
    \end{itemize}
  \item six
  \item sep
  \item hui
  \item neu
  \item dix
  \item onz
  \item dou


\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
  \item un
  \item deu
    \begin{itemize}
      \item deuzième niveau
      \item ...
    \end{itemize}
  \item trois
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


note that the bullet you get is font dependent. you get a square bullet if your font provides a square, a round if it provides round and a spiral if it provides a spiral. the defaults have to work with all fonts, including the base set. so you get the bullet point. after that, you have to use something else. they are not pictures. they are characters from fonts, which is why you get something different if you change font.

I can't reproduce a square bullet by switching to sans. what exactly did you do? the only place I've seen this by default is in Beamer presentations?

that's right, here it is: \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

That doesn't produce a square bullet. It doesn't even switch to sans. In the code below, I switch to sans, too, but I still get round bullets because that's what is provided by default. If you get a square, you are using code you've not shown.

@user1850133 Can you please add a short example which reproduces the square bullet?

i just checked, I also get round bullets in first level if i build with pdflatex. Actually it's been long that i shifted for lualatex because it has native utf8 support. So try compiling with lualatex my mwe.

The default fonts provide a round bullet whether you use serif or sans. I cannot reproduce the behaviour you report concerning a square bullet when sans is used.
Note that the code you provided doesn't actually use sans at all. In the code below, I switch to sans, but obviously this changes the output. This demonstrates the default, round bullet for the first level and an open round bullet for the second.
To access the standard bullet directly, use \textbullet in text mode. Don't use a maths symbol here.
Note that the symbols are not drawn. They are taken from the active fonts. So, if you find your bullets becoming squares or octagons or goggling eyes, that's the font you've chosen. All LaTeX does it take the specified character from the appropriate font1.
If you are using a Unicode engine, you shouldn't load fontenc, as I have below. But if you are using pdfTeX, you should use T1 encoding for French. I realise you may do this in your real document.
I've also used the standard \textcircled{} for the enumeration labels.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for pdfTeX - delete for LuaTeX or XeTeX
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\protect\textcircled{\tiny\arabic*}}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\textopenbullet}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}% has no effect in this example
\sffamily % actually use sans

\begin{enumerate}
  \item un
  \item deu

    \begin{itemize}
      \item deuzième niveau
      \item ...
    \end{itemize}

  \item tro
  \item qua
  \item cin
    \begin{itemize}
      \item deuzième niveau
      \item \dots
    \end{itemize}
  \item six
  \item sep
  \item hui
  \item neu
  \item dix
  \item onz
  \item dou
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
  \item un
  \item deu
    \begin{itemize}
      \item deuzième niveau
      \item \dots
    \end{itemize}
  \item trois
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


1Technically, all LaTeX does is create a box for the character to fit into. If pdfTeX is used as the engine, the character is also added. otherwise, it is the job of the DVI viewer or post-processor to actually add the glyph.
